# Rails has_many through multiple foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given this:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parents
  has_many :children, through: :parents
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :house
  has_many :children, ->(parent) { unscope(:where).where("mother_id = :id OR father_id = :id", id: parent.id) }
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :mother, class_name: 'Parent'
  belongs_to :father, class_name: 'Parent'
end
```

I'm trying to do:

```
Parent.last.children.count # WORKS
House.last.parents.count # WORKS
House.last.children.count # DOESN'T WORK

no such column: children.parent_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "children" INNER JOIN "parents" ON "children"."parent_id" = "parents"."id" WHERE (mother_id = 1 OR father_id = 1)
```

Is there any way to fix `has_many :children, through: :parents`? It should return children as `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` (not an `Array`). Perhaps some clever join?

Comment: Seems like a bad design to assume there's one mother and one father in the house! I hope you're not running this design in production (with a large user base), or this will inevitably cause issues...(Or is this database schema only to demonstrate the structure, and your real code is something completely different?)

Comment: Correct, it's only to illustrate the structure. It's actually about something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the default join in `has_many :children` in house.rb is between the children and parents table depending on the `parent_id` column that is not exist.

so you need to override it: so house.rb should look like below.

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parents
  has_many :children, -> { unscope(:joins).joins('INNER JOIN ON children.father_id = parents.id OR children.mother_id = parents.id') }, through: :parents
end
```